# Is it possible to create a write-only folder where a user can drop files in but can't see the folders content?

Tags: permissions, sftp

I'm trying to create a folder for an SFTP user, where the user can drop files into it but can't see/list any files under that folder. Pretty much a "blind drop". It is OK to overwrite files while dropping same name files.

Is this possible to achieve?

I have tried few online documents however I couldn't managed to get it working.

Comment: Should the same blind drop directory be used by many users? Or can you create separate blind drop directories for each of these users?

Comment: I have two users sharing same home folder. One of the user should be able to have read/write access and other one should have write-only access to same folder. So technically there will be only one write-only user, but also a secondary user with read-write access. Both users are member of (the same) ftp group.

Comment: If it is OK to see files, when the user specifies the full name, it is easy. Remove read access, add write access, keep execute access. -- But *please tell us why you want 'blind drop'*. It seems to me to be secret only for the person who puts files there, at least if we are talking about a separate dedicated directory. And is it a good idea to allow overwriting a file that somebody else has written?

Comment: You can easily deny a user to list contents of a folder while while retaining write access by removing the `r`ead permissions of a directory, setting it to `-wx`. But this still allows them to open and read all files in there if they know the exact filename. Is that okay? Otherwise you would probably have to set up a script that monitors your drop folder and moves all files away as soon as they get created.

Comment: Also what about directories? Those could become a problem if your user tries to create or move a directory there and you have a watcher script running that moves everything away while it is still being accessed.

Comment: having the "blind drop" folder is a customer requirement, so not my decision really. I also think it is not a good idea. Customer insists they were using a write only folder before. I have tried giving -wx, still getting permission denied when I try and transfer files over FTP/SFTP. script would be a workaround however I'm quite sure customer wouldn't agree with that. creating folder might be an issue but I think that won't be the case since the plan is uploading text files only

Comment: The user ID, that is logged in should have write and execute permissions for the directory, for example because it belongs to a group that has those permissions. I am talking about the user ID in the server. What do you mean  by 'ftp group'?